# Align with specific element of neighbouring cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I don't know if this is even possible using tables, so I'm open to suggestions using e.g. flexbox.

In a two-columned table, the left column has some text, the right columns has an image and some text. I want to vertically align the left column's text with the middle of the right column's image. I've tried using absolute positioning but they can be variable sized so it does not scale correctly for different screen sizes, and I really don't know how else to approach the problem. Also, the fact that it's not just the image in the cell means that `vertical-align: middle` cannot be used.

Here's what I'm dealing with:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>I want to be aligned with the middle of the image</td>
      <td>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        <p>
          Some more text, possible over multiple lines.
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

[Relevant JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lj6fg9ad/).

Comment: Could you put the text of the right column in a different cell than that of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately vertical-align doesn’t apply to block-level elements, which is where most of us figure out it isn’t the be all solution to vertical centering. However, we have other methods like "line-height" for centering block level elements and we can still use vertical-align where appropriate.

**You can go with this:**

```css
.vericalAlignment{
  line-height: 150px;
  vertical-align: baseline; 
  //Drop vertical-align class on your td so you don't have to overrride it here.
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="vericalAlignment">I want to be aligned with the middle of the image</td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
      <p>
        Some more text, possible over multiple lines.
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have this layout using display grid (I don't think it's possible with table)

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

span {
    grid-column: 1;
    align-self: center;
}

img {
    grid-column: 2;
}

p {
    grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>I want to be aligned with the middle of the image</span>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <p>Some more text, possible over multiple lines.</p>
    <span>I want to be aligned with the middle of the image</span>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <p>Some more text, possible over multiple lines.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to apply this solution while retaining table semantics, you can do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/c9367aty/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="tab">I want to be aligned with the middle of the image</td>
      <td>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        <p>
          Some more text, possible over multiple lines.
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

css

```
  table{
   margin-top:55px;
  }



 .tab {
   width:80px;
   padding-left:50px;
   text-align:center;
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Opera 10.5 */
   -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* IE older versions */
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
  /* IE newer versions */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
  /* Standard */
   transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  }
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/84t7kzx6/

or this

```
   <table>
   <tr>
     <td class="tab">I want to be aligned with the middle of the image</td>
     <td>
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
       <p>
         Some more text, possible over multiple lines.
       </p>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

css

```
 .tab {


   align-items:center;
   padding-top:auto;

   padding-bottom:55px;


   }
```

Comment: It has been a long time since last time I saw code for IE6 ...........

Comment: It's for the people who still use IE6 .BTW this is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is what some other folks have said: put the text below the image in a new row.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      I want to be aligned with the middle of the image
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <p>
        Some more text, possible over multiple lines.
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```